# java run cmd commands

Tags: java, cmd, pscp

I have some problem about run windows cmd ,when I run my code on GEL or some java tool,it works,but it run error that windows can't find "pscp".However,I export execute jar from eclipse and java -jar ..It works!! I set pscp path first, so i can type pscp commend on cmd.

```
String file="test5.pdf";

String Ip="140.118.175.196";
String commend="cmd.exe /c start pscp.exe d://"+file+" admin@"+Ip+":/home/admin/test";

Process ee = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commend);
```

What happen? Thanks.

Comment: if you type pscp in the cmd prompt manually what do you get? looks like putty is not on your path

Comment: I place my putty and pscp on C://putty/ and i can run this commend line on cmd directly. I type pscp and i can get commend option ,It seems no problem?

Comment: but if you run it from c: for example does it find pscp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pscp.exe` is not in your path. You need to add it to your path or put in the command string the complete path to the `pscp.exe` executable.